# Can't iterate through array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array in javascript and I can't access any data in it. The array prints out like this:
[console View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59C77.png)

**EDIT**
This is my code: The issue is it's not getting anything from data[x], and data is the name of my array

```
for (var x in data) {
    yaxis.push(data[x].dateAdded);
    xaxis.push(data[x].priority);
    text_hover.push(data[x].name + ' - ' + data[x].organType);
}
```

I guess my issue is that its telling me my length is 0, but when in fact it is 1

Comment: The Array has on Object in it. What's the question here?

Comment: show your code and then we can go on from there.

Comment: Looks like it's an array of objects. What do you want to achieve from iterating the array? We can help if you can share your code.

Comment: @NickA but, its not even hitting the inside of the loop. And when I print the length of the array, its giving me 0, but when I print the array like `console.log(data)` its giving me the picture above.

Comment: @user3324236 this seems like a problem with the way you're obtaining your data (asynchronous?), providing more code about how you get `data` may help.

Comment: Yea that was it, figured it out this morning! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

To me this looks like your array has one item in it so

```
array.forEach( item => console.log( item.HLAType ))
```

should work or

```
array[0].HLAType
```

if however as someone suggested you want to print all the properties on your object you need to do:

```
let obj = array[0];
Object.keys(obj).forEach( key => {
  console.log( obj[key] )  //prints the value of said key
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s not really clear from your question what exactly – that is, which statement(s) – is troubling you. I’ll guess you’re searching for (for instance) a line like `var objectsOrganSize = myArray[0].organSize;` (if your array is called `myArray`).

Or iterating through it:

```
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
    console.log(myArray[i].organSize);
}
```

If, on the other hand, you’re confusing arrays with objects and actually want to iterate through `organSize`, `bloodType`, etc., look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties#16735184)

### EDIT

Your code looks suspiciously like an asynchronous request. Could it be that your loop is executed when the data has not returned yet from the server. Or are you maybe accessing it outside of the callback function, so `data` is undefined?

Comment: I’ve seen this answer getting 2 upvotes and 2 downvotes. Since I’m new to this site, I’d like to encourage the downvoters to leave a note on what I could have improved.

Comment: I would guess the downvotes are because you've clearly stated its not clear what's being asked.  If it's not clear what is being asked **don't answer**. If you dont have the reputation to comment you'll just have to find questions you can answer without clarification.

Comment: @NickA Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @NIckA 

I don’t have enough reputation to comment on the question, so I’ll hope you’ll read this.

With `data=[{key1 : 'value 1'}];`, `for(x in data) console.log(data[x])` yields `> Object { key1: "value 1" }`, whereas `for(x in data) console.log(x)` yields `> 0`. Unlike in Java, the for-in-loop returns the key, not the referenced object.

Comment: JS isnt my best language and i'm not on my PC atm, but given you're updates to the answer following the question changes I feel the answer is more appropriate, I merely meant that for future reference you shoild refrain from answering a question until there are enough details to provide an appropriate answer, indeed this is difficult before you can comment but you should be able to find some good questions that can be answered without clarification that will provide enough reputation to comment in future.

Comment: I fully got your point. Personally, I thought it was more appropriate to _try_ to help than not to help at all; but if things are handled here differently, I’ll try to void guessing an answer. Luckily, I’ve got the privilege by now. —— As for my second remark (the JS stuff), I was referencing your comment (which you seem to have deleted) on the question itself stating that the ``for(x in data)`` loop returned the object itself.

Comment: Indeed, I had expected it to return the objects like a `for .. in` loop in python, however that was incorrect.